# How to find value in array based conditional

Tags: c#, arrays, vb.net

I was collect data an array with 2 coloumn look like this

```
---------------
Order  | Value
---------------
order1 | 45
order2 | 70
order1 | 85
order2 | 32
--------------
```

How to get all value in the array based conditional where order= order1 only and sum them?

Thank you,

Comment: I'd use LINQ. Have you looked at that at all yet? If so, show what you've tried and what went wrong. (Hint: you should be able to do it with a call to `Where` and a call to `Sum`.) It's not really clear why you're using a 2D array rather than a type which encapsulates the order name and value, mind you. It's also not clear whether this is a rectangular array or a jagged array. A [mcve] would make it easier to help you.

Comment: @JonSkeet I don't think he meant a 2-D array (the one we know it) because I don't think a 2-D array can hold a string in one dimension and a number in the second. Unless it is an object array (which is unlikely)

Comment: @user3185569: It's hard to tell for sure, to be honest. That's why I asked for a [mcve].

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Linq (`Where` for Conditional) and (`Sum` for Aggregate Functions):

```
var sum = array.Where(x=> x.Order == "order1").Sum(x=> x.Value);
```

If you really meant a 2-D (Multidimentional) Array, then you can do this:

```
object[,] array = 
{
    { "order1", 45 }, { "order2", 70 },
    { "order1", 85 }, { "order2", 32 }
};


decimal Sum = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if (array.GetValue(i, 0)?.ToString() == "order1")
    {
        decimal val;
        if(decimal.TryParse(array.GetValue(i, 1)?.ToString(), out val))
            Sum += val;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give me a complete code. I just started with simple array from this :

string[,] ord = new string[7, 3];

How to implement that linq code with that array? Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much. But if you deign, how if I not use 2D array, like this array :
string[,] ord = new string[7, 3];  Please check the edited post. So how to started use linq if using that array?

Comment: @MFBM you can't use linq to get each row. You can use linq to get each element separately. Like `order1`, `45`, `order2`, `70`.

Comment: Thank you very much. But I still dificult to understand how to write in VB.NET code. I have try to manipulation your solution and convert into VB.Net code but is nothing. So can you help me, how if that solution writen with VB code If you have VB language? Btw Thanks you in advance

Comment: Hi Sehnsucht, Thank you for your help!